# Mongoose: Can I clone a mongoose Schema but make modifications to it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have a mongoose schema like

```
{
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

And all I want to do is clone the schema, but remove all required validation. So its like

```
{
  name: String,
  email: { type: String }
}
```

Isit possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to make modifications while cloning the mongoose Schema, you can only extend the Schema to support a new prop(s) in the Schema but can't really change the previous ones.